# QComboBox - Which is better to use? findText or findData - Qt

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to select a item from QcomboBox.

```
index = combobox.findText("D:\Squisher\squish\SQUISH_TESTS_TRUNK_2018x_TNA8\suite_DeltaGen\tst_LookAndShadow_2\testdata\ref\SurroundingsCompleted\Backplates\coast_backplate_test.tif")
if index >= 0:
    combobox.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

This is how i m selecting a value. But Sometime, findText is returning -1 even if the value present in Combobox. so i m thinking to use findData instead of findText.
What is the difference between findText and findData ? Which is better and Why?

Comment: Could you indicate how you set the items in the QComboBox?

Comment: Windows file-paths are *case-insensitive*, so you should use `combobox.findText(path, Qt.MatchFixedString)`. There is no point in using `findData`, which is just a more complicated way of doing the same thing.